# LED doesn't turn on as specified on code State Machine

Tags: arduino-uno, led

This is the question from the homework I'm doing "Design and implement a state machine with a single button to turn on and off two LEDs The first LED should be turned on and off with a quick press of the button, the second LED should turn on and off with a long press (1 second)."

I have this code

```
int state_s1 = 0;
int state_s2 = 0;
int state_s3 = 0;
int state_s4 = 0;
int state_prev_s1 =0;
int ledPin2 = 8;
int ledPin = 9;
int boton = 10;
int boton2 = 11;
int val_s1 = 0;
unsigned long t_0_s1 = 0;
unsigned long t_s1 = 0;
unsigned long t_s2 = 0;
unsigned long tiempo = 50;
unsigned long bounce_delay_s1 = 5;
unsigned long bounce_delay_s2 = 1000;
boolean prendido = false;
boolean prendidoP = false;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(boton, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(boton2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop()
{

  SM_s1();  

  if(prendido == true)
  {
    led();
  }  

  if(prendidoP == true)
  {
    led2();
  }  

   Serial.print("state 1 =");
   Serial.println(state_s1);

   Serial.println("************");

}

void led()
{

  switch(state_s1)
  {      
    case 0:         //OFF
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    t_0_s1 = millis();
    state_s1 = 1;
    break;

    case 1:         //WAIT
    t_s1 = millis();
    if(t_s1 - t_0_s1 >= tiempo)
    {
      state_s1 = 2;
    }
    break;

    case 2:         // ON
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    t_0_s1 = millis();
    state_s1 = 3;
    break;

    case 3:         //WAIT   
    t_s1 = millis();
    if(t_s1 - t_0_s1 >= tiempo)  
    {
     state_s1 = 0;
    }
    break;


  }
}

void led2()
{

  switch(state_s4)
  {      
    case 0:         //OFF
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
    t_0_s1 = millis();
    state_s4 = 1;
    break;

    case 1:         //WAIT
    t_s1 = millis();
    if(t_s1 - t_0_s1 >= tiempo)
    {
      state_s4 = 2;
    }
    break;

    case 2:         // ON
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
    t_0_s1 = millis();
    state_s4 = 3;
    break;

    case 3:         //WAIT   
    t_s1 = millis();
    if(t_s1 - t_0_s1 >= tiempo)  
    {
     state_s4 = 0;
    }
    break;


  }
}

 void SM_s1()
 {
  switch(state_s2)
  {
    case 0:         //RESET
    state_s2 = 1;
    break;

    case 1:        //START
    val_s1 = digitalRead(boton);
    if(val_s1 == LOW)
     {
      state_s2 = 2;
     }
    break;

    case 2:         // GO!
    t_0_s1 = millis();
    state_s2 = 3;
    break;

    case 3:         //WAIT
   if(val_s1 == HIGH)
     {
      state_s2 = 0;
     }

    t_s1 = millis();

    if(t_s1 - t_0_s1 >= bounce_delay_s1)
    {
      state_s2 = 5;
    }
    break;

    case 5:         //ARMED & WAIT
    t_s2 = millis();
    val_s1 = digitalRead(boton);
    if(val_s1 == HIGH && t_s2-t_s1 < bounce_delay_s2)
     {
      state_s2 = 4;
     }

     if(t_s2-t_s1 >= bounce_delay_s2)
     { 
      state_s2= 6;
     }

    break;

    case 4:       //TRIGGERED
    state_s2 = 0;
    prendido = not prendido; 
    break;


    case 6:     // ARMED 2
    state_s2 = 0;
    prendidoP = not prendidoP; 
    break;

}
}
```

It will work the first time but then the LEDs won't turn off and sometimes when the button is pressed hard, it will turn both LEDs on, please help me.

Comment: please use the `{}` button to format the code

Comment: how do you press a button hard? ... is the button touch sensitive?

Comment: case 3 never reads if the button is pressed. It only uses the old value stored in case 1. I think case 3 should start with a `val_s1 = digitalRead(boton);`

Comment: Do you have the state-diagram for us, as the code is hard to understand with all those meaningless variable names.